# Trama de web service

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un Web Service y quiero imprimir las tramas de comunicacion que ingresan y la respuesta que sale.

Realizo el web service con el wizar de Netbeans con contener Tomcat y se realizo con la libreria Metro.

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "test")
public class test {

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "largo")
    public String largo(@WebParam(name = "palabras") String[] palabras) {
    System.out.println("tam" + palabras.length);
     return "Tam " + palabras.length;
    }
}
```

La idea es imprimir las tramas como sale en una prueba de SoapUI al momento que consumen el servicio.

Agradesco cualquier ayuda

Comment: A que te refieres con trama? puedes aclarar eso ademas de proveer mas informacion en lo que quieres lograr

Comment: Cuando realizo la consulta ver las peticiones (informacion) que se envia y su respuesta a nivel de trasas XML asi como se ve en las aplicacion es de pruebas,  asi:

Comment: informacion que se recibe:    
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:pru="http://prueba/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <pru:largo>
             <palabras>45465</palabras>
             <palabras>45465</palabras>
          <palabras>45465</palabras>
          </pru:largo>
       </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
   
Y la informacion que retorna:
   <S:Envelope>
     <S:Body>
          <ns2:receptorResponse xmlns:ns2="http://prueba/">
             <return>Tam 3</return>
          </ns2:receptorResponse>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>